# Sequentially execute the functions? Not sure how to precisely describe the question

Tags: javascript

I run into a problem trying to solve it; but somehow stuck in the middle. The problem is to implement a function $do() which could take any number of functions and execute them in the order they were called.
In the specific example, print a in 700 ms and b in 200, then print c in 100ms. The challenge part is although c should be print first, but it is called after in the $do() after a and b get called. 
My implementation as below, almost working, but cannot print c for some reason. Help needed. Thanks a lot.

```
const a = (cb) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        cb();
        console.log('a', 700);
    }, 700);
};

const b = (cb) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        cb();
        console.log('b', 200);
    }, 200);
};


const c = (cb) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        cb();
        console.log('c', 100);
    }, 100);
};

const stores = [];
let running = false;

function $do() {
    const cbs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    stores.push(cbs);
    let i = 0;

    while (stores.length > 0 && !running) {
        let head = stores.shift();
        running = i < head.length;

        head.forEach((cb) => {
            cb(() => {
                i++;
                running = i < head.length;
                console.log(running);
            });
        });
    }
}

$do(a, b);
$do(c);
```

Comment: sorry for my not-clear description. You answer is neat. But the expected result should sequentially be  ```
b 200
a 700 c 100``` since c gets called after a and b although c has the smallest timeout

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses a closure and [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for each of the previous pending invocations of `$do()` to complete before calling each of the functions provided in the current invocation.

This means that `c` will not be called until both `a` and `b` have called back:

```js
const delay = (name, ms) => cb => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    cb()
    console.log(name, ms)
  }, ms)
}

const a = delay('a', 700)
const b = delay('b', 200)
const c = delay('c', 100)

const $do = (() => {
  let done = Promise.resolve()

  return (...fns) => {
    done = done.then(
      () => Promise.all(fns.map(fn => new Promise(fn)))
    )
  }
})()

$do(a, b)
$do(c)
```

Comment: definitely a better answer :p

Comment: sorry for my not-clear description. You answer is neat. But the expected result should sequentially be  ```
b 200
a 700 c 100``` since c gets called after a and b although c has the smallest timeout

Comment: @lxx22 see my updated answer. I removed the `running` logs for simplicity but I can add them back if you want to see where those go as well.

Comment: nice - took me a while to understand how the promises get resolved :p

Comment: Each function becomes the executor in the `Promise` constructor, so the callback function passed to each one is `resolve`.

Answer (score 0):

Using an IIFE below only to avoid polluting the global namespace unnecessarily

One thing that I'm not sure of is pushing an array onto stores - if there were no "processing" the array would end up

```
[[a, b],[c]]
```

and the processing you require would be a, then b, then c - so stores could just as easily be

```
[a, b, c]
```

Which is what the code below does, by the way

```js
const a = (cb) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        cb();
        console.log('a', 700);
    }, 700);
};

const b = (cb) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        cb();
        console.log('b', 200);
    }, 200);
};


const c = (cb) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        cb();
        console.log('c', 100);
    }, 100);
};
// NOTE: I only use the IIFE to not polute GLOBAL namespace with stores and running variables
const $do = (() => {
    const stores = [];
    let running = false;

    let process = () => {
        const cb = stores.shift();
        cb(() => {
            running = !!stores.length;
            if (running) {
                process();
            }
        });
    };
    return (...cbs) => {
        stores.push(...cbs);
        if (!running) {
            running = true;
            process();
        }
    };
})();

$do(a, b);
$do(c);
```

Comment: sorry for my not-clear description. You answer is neat. But the expected result should sequentially be  ```
b 200
a 700 c 100``` since c gets called after a and b although c has the smallest timeout

Comment: your question states `c should be print first` - sorry if I misunderstood

Comment: @lxx22 - updated again, there was some unnecessary rubbish in my code :p